# date inequality in sql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the following situation:

```
declare @b datetime 
declare @d datetime 
set @b='2014-01-31 00:00:00.000'
set @d='2014-01-31 00:00:00.000'--NULL

IF @b <> @d
    PRINT 'N'
ELSE
    PRINT 'Y'
```

The above code behaves fine when @b and @d are valid values.
But it fails to compare when either of them is null.
What then is the recommended way,since I have null to be a possible/acceptable case in an inequality check too?

I am using MSSQL2008

Comment: A comparison with `NULL` is "undefined". I'm not sure about SQL Server, but standard SQL allows the operator `is distinct from` which handles nulls. In your case you need to explicitly check for nulls using `IS NULL` or using `coalesce()` to "convert" NULL to some default value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT @b EXCEPT SELECT @d)
    PRINT 'N'
ELSE
    PRINT 'Y'
```

Comment: I like this answer, simple !

Answer (score 0):

`null` is not a value in SQL - it is the lack of a value. Hence, when you compare it with any real value, the retsult is unkown, which does not evaluate to `true`.

If you want to handle `null`s, you should do so explicitly. E.g.:

```
IF (@B IS NULL AND @d IS NOT NULL) OR (@B IS NOT NULL AND @d IS NULL) OR (@b <> @d))
    PRINT 'N'
ELSE
    PRINT 'Y'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change the settings to fit your requirements:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
declare @b datetime 
declare @d datetime 
set @b='2014-01-31 00:00:00.000'
set @d='2014-01-31 00:00:00.000'--NULL

IF @b <> @d
    PRINT 'N'
ELSE
    PRINT 'Y'
```

Comment: This setting is deprecated though. [Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx)

Comment: @MartinSmith you just made my day. I always hated that setting